# C# Tree view List child nodes

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

I'm having trouble getting all the child nodes listed correctly. I have a list of "employees" that has a list inside that is for hardware checked out. The Employee names and id show just fine. I just can't get more than 1 of the hardware checked out showing.

Here is what I have so far.

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        // sorts the fields by ascending order.
        frmCheckOut.checkedOutItem.SortList();

        // Clears the Tree View so there is no duplicate entries.
        tvInventory.Nodes.Clear();

        TreeNode date = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode[] nodeArray = new TreeNode[1];
        TreeNode itemDescription = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode[] nodeArray2 = new TreeNode[1];
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();

        foreach(CheckOutItem item in frmCheckOut.checkedOutItem.itemCollection)
       {
            foreach (Hardware h in item.hardware)
            {
                date = new TreeNode(h.Date);
                nodeArray = new TreeNode[] { date };
                itemDescription = new TreeNode(h.HName + ": " + h.TagNumber, nodeArray);
                nodeArray2 = new TreeNode[] { itemDescription };
            }

            treeNode = new TreeNode(item.EmpNumber + " " + item.LastName + ", " + item.FirstName + "<" + item.Email + ">", nodeArray2);

            tvInventory.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

        }
    }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried seeing how many Hardware objects are in the CheckOutItem 'item'? - what was the count (.Count)?

Comment: There is 2. I can add as many as I want. They still only add one. Is it how I have the loop?

Comment: You are not adding the hardware nodes to the employee nodes inside the hardware loop.  It's being done outside the loop, so only the last one is getting added.

Comment: Okay. How would I make one employee node for all the hardware nodes for that employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with it more. I came up with this solution. It works quite well. Thanks for all the comment guys!

```
private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        // sorts the fields by ascending order.
        frmCheckOut.checkedOutItem.SortList();

        // Clears the Tree View so there is no duplicate entries.
        tvInventory.Nodes.Clear();


        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();

        foreach(CheckOutItem item in frmCheckOut.checkedOutItem.itemCollection)
       {
            treeNode = new TreeNode(item.EmpNumber + " " + item.LastName + ", " + item.FirstName + "<" + item.Email + ">");

            tvInventory.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        }

        AddChildNodes();
    }

    private void AddChildNodes()
    {
        TreeNode date = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode[] nodeArray = new TreeNode[1];
        TreeNode itemDescription = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode[] nodeArray2 = new TreeNode[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < tvInventory.Nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (CheckOutItem item in frmCheckOut.checkedOutItem.itemCollection)
            {
                foreach (Hardware h in item.hardware)
                {
                    date = new TreeNode(h.Date);
                    nodeArray = new TreeNode[] { date };
                    itemDescription = new TreeNode(h.HName + ": " + h.TagNumber, nodeArray);
                    tvInventory.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(itemDescription);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```